# Minimum number of boxes required for n objects

Tags: arrays, algorithm

There are n objects having different weights. We have to find the minimum number of boxes required to pack all weights where each box can have the maximum weight of K. Boxes can have any number of objects but weight should be less than or equal to given weight K.

All weights are less than or equal to K.

For example, let K= 13 and objects be {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} than minimum number of boxes required are 4 ,i.e, {4,9}, {5,8}, {6,7}, {2,3}

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe this would help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Answer (score -2):

It is almost similar to the 0-1 knapsack problem. It can be solved using dynamic programming. The difference between the classic knapsack problem and your's is that in your case there are multiple knapsacks.

> The knapsack problem or rucksack problem is a problem in combinatorial
>   optimization: Given a set of items, each with a weight and a value,
>   determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that
>   the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total
>   value is as large as possible.

Source - Wikipedia

[Here's](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/) the algorithm and a nice explanation.